# How to change objects at the same time in fireworks?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, style

I haven't used Adobe Fireworks in a long time, but today I have used it again to try create some object. Anyway, I remember that when I last used fireworks there was something you can do so that if you copy an object such as a circle or a rectangle then when you change the new object's color or size then the old object changes as well. As I said I havn't used fireworks for a long time and I don't remember if this property is in fireworks or in some other application.

Do anyone know if this property exists in fireworks?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about creating symbols perhaps? More info [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00db4b-7fd4.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Convert to symbol feature. Right click on the desired shape or a selection of multiple shapes > `Convert to symbol`. Then make a copy of the symbol. Double click on any copy to enter edit mode. Any changes will be applied to all copies in real time.